# expose js modules in webpack like done in browserify (it uses 'expose' option in .require)

Tags: javascript, webpack, browserify

In browserify there is an option called 'expose' in browserify.require() method that takes in a string and makes the module required be available by the value of that expose property.

```
browserify.require('./path/to/file.js',{expose:'ipsem'});
```

then if we use
    var IPSEM = require('ipsem');
we will get the './path/to/file.js' module in IPSEM.

Now I want to do the same thing in webpack. Any idea how it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the resolve.modules options. By default, it's using node_modules but you can modify it to add the modules you want.

More info here: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-modules